# Where the test file should be placed when converting selenium project into maven project in eclipse

Tags: java, maven, selenium, testing, src

Normally in maven project I place the test file into

```
src/java/test because src/java/test
```

path is already created by maven when creating new maven project.It works fine.But now I convert the developed selenium project into maven project.In this case where can i place the test file because I don't have path 
src/java/test path.How can I resolve it?

Comment: create it manually ? Or i advise you to create a new `maven project` and copy all contents that you have in your project in the new empty maven project

Comment: Thanks,I already refer this link http://toolsqa.com/java/maven/configure-selenium-continuous-integration-maven/. As per this link i did,the browser does not open and no error will be displayed.Don't know the reason why it does not properly work?

Comment: As i said, better create a new empty project maven and copy all your folders of your existing project into it ... It's too much easier and better and it will work.

Comment: Bunch of thanks,it works fine.

Comment: No problem happy for you